# Levenshtein Distance Algorithm better than O(n*m)?

Tags: ios, algorithm, big-o, levenshtein-distance

I have been looking for an advanced levenshtein distance algorithm, and [the best I have found so far](http://www.levenshtein.net/) is O(n*m) where n and m are the lengths of the two strings. The reason why the algorithm is at this scale is because of space, not time, with the creation of a matrix of the two strings such as this one:

[image]

**Is there a publicly-available levenshtein algorithm which is better than O(n*m)?** I am not averse to looking at advanced computer science papers & research, but haven't been able to find anything. I have found one company, Exorbyte, which supposedly has built a super-advanced and super-fast Levenshtein algorithm but of course that is a trade secret. I am building an iPhone app which I would like to use the Levenshtein distance calculation. [There is an objective-c implementation available](http://www.merriampark.com/ldobjc.htm), but with the limited amount of memory on iPods and iPhones, I'd like to find a better algorithm if possible.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Are you  interested in reducing the time complexity or the space complexity ? The average time complexity can be reduced O(n + d^2), where n is the length of the longer string and d is the edit distance. If you are only interested in the edit distance and not interested in reconstructing the edit sequence, you only need to keep the last two rows of the matrix in memory, so that will be order(n).

If you can afford to approximate, there are poly-logarithmic approximations.

For the O(n +d^2) algorithm look for Ukkonen's optimization or its enhancement [Enhanced Ukkonen](http://www.berghel.net/publications/asm/asm.php). The best approximation that I know of is this one by  [Andoni, Krauthgamer, Onak](http://people.csail.mit.edu/konak/papers/approximating_edit_distance.html)

Comment: I use this for DNA alignment; We check for the length of the sequences first since the logic for updating the Ukkonen barrier is heavier then just calculating the whole array. Also, take a look at "Time Warps, String Edits, and Macromolecules: The Theory and Practice of Sequence Comparison" for some more details.

Comment: The original paper for the Ukkonen Approximate String Matching Algorithm is, http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/InfCont85.PDF.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the last two rows of the matrix. The last row, plus the previous number in the current row, is enough. Also note that implementing Levenshtein this way is significantly faster than using the full matrix, probably due to CPU caching.

Comment: An implementation of the Extended Ukkonen algorithm is [here](https://github.com/haifengl/smile/blob/master/math/src/main/java/smile/math/distance/EditDistance.java). It requires a lot of space (O(mn)), but runs quickly when the strings are similar - probably the formula O(n+d^2) is correct for its time complexity. Make sure to call the right constructor (the one with maxStringLength) and reuse the EditDistance instance to get the benefits (otherwise array initialization cost negates them).

Comment: @nlucaroni do you compare two strings always or are you trying to find a fuzzy match for a sequence within large database?

Comment: The former, this isn't an EST searching solution.

Answer (score 14):

If you only want the threshold function - eg, to test if the distance is under a certain threshold - you can reduce the time and space complexity by only calculating the n values either side of the main diagonal in the array. You can also use [Levenshtein Automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata) to evaluate many words against a single base word in O(n) time - and the construction of the automatons can be done in O(m) time, too.

Comment: And how is it possible that with only one side you know that the other side does not have a path with less distance? That would mean calculating the minimum distance with just one half.
And the main diagonal? If strings have different sizes the main diagonal does not even reach the end of the matrix. I think I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: This blog is really great for understanding the concept http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata

Answer (score 3):

Look in Wiki - they have some ideas to improve this algorithm to better space complexity:

[Wiki-Link: Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Quoting:

> We can adapt the algorithm to use less space, O(m) instead of O(mn), since it only requires that the previous row and current row be stored at any one time.

Comment: One explained in wikipedia for space complexity that is using two rows does not provide correct solution for strings where length(s)>length(t). Lets say to convert S=ab to T=abcd we need two changes. That solution gives 1 as answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the two strings being compared may have different lengths and that the square portion of the matrix is nearly symmetric, you can leverage this symmetry to reduce the number of computations by calculating either the upper or lower triangular portion of the matrix. However, occasional deviations in symmetry may occur when a letter from one string matches a letter in the other string, but their indices differ. In such cases, the value in the larger triangular portion is the only value of the two that can impact the final result. Therefore, only the larger triangular portion needs to be calculated. Here is a Java implementation that reduces the time complexity to O(n^2), where n is the length of the shorter string:
[(Modified from this page)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/damerau-levenshtein-distance/)

```
public static int optimalStringAlignmentDistance(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
        return optimalStringAlignmentDistance(s2, s1);
    }

    // Initialize the table
    int[][] dp = new int[s1.length()+1][s2.length()+1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
        dp[i][0] = i;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
        dp[0][j] = j;
    }

    // Populate the table using dynamic programming
    for (int i = 1; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i-1) == s2.charAt(j-1)) {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1];
            } else {
                int topMin = Math.min(dp[i-1][j-1], dp[i-1][j]);
                if (j == i) {
                    // dp[i][j-1] is not in this triangular portion
                    dp[i][j] = 1 + topMin;
                } else {
                    dp[i][j] = 1 + Math.min(topMin, dp[i][j-1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the edit distance
    return dp[s1.length()][s2.length()];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found another optimization that claims to be O(max(m, n)):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C

(the second C implementation)

Comment: The OP was takling about time complexity, not memory