# Levenshtein / edit distance for arbitrary sequences

Tags: r, unicode, levenshtein-distance

I want to compute the Levenshtein distance between two arbitrary sequences.

```
a <- 1:100
b <- c(1, 1:100)

edit_distance(a, b) == 1
```

I am aware of the `adist` function and the `stringdist` package, but they only work on character vectors. If the number of symbols in the sequences were small, I could just encode them as characters and use the above functions.

But there will typically be on the order of 1000 different symbols. Another option would be to encode them as Unicode characters (`adist` works on them: `adist("\U00001", "\U00001\U00002")`), but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Maybe the `jmotif` package would be worth a look. Not sure it is exactly what you are looking for, but has some overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `intToUtf8` to map your integers to Unicode characters:

```
a2 <- intToUtf8(a)
b2 <- intToUtf8(b)

adist(a2, b2)
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
```