# Is this Levenshtein Distance algorithm correct?

Tags: c#, algorithm, distance, levenshtein-distance

I have written the algorithm below to compute the Levenshtein distance, and it seems to return the correct results based on my tests. The time complexity is O(n+m), and the space is O(1).

All the existing algorithms I've seen only for this have space complexity O(n*m), as they create a matrix. Is there something wrong with my algorithm?

```
public static int ComputeLevenshteinDistance(string word1, string word2)
{
    var index1 = 0;
    var index2 = 0;
    var numDeletions = 0;
    var numInsertions = 0;
    var numSubs = 0;
    while (index1 < word1.Length || index2 < word2.Length)
    {
        if (index1 == word1.Length)
        {
            // Insert word2[index2]
            numInsertions++;
            index2++;
        }
        else if (index2 == word2.Length)
        {
            // Delete word1[index1]
            numDeletions++;
            index1++;
        }
        else if (word1[index1] == word2[index2])
        {
            // No change as word1[index1] == word2[index2]
            index1++;
            index2++;
        }
        else if (index1 < word1.Length - 1 && word1[index1 + 1] == word2[index2])
        {
            // Delete word1[index1]
            numDeletions++;
            index1++;
        }
        else if (index2 < word2.Length - 1 && word1[index1] == word2[index2 + 1])
        {
            // Insert word2[index2]
            numInsertions++;
            index2++;
        }
        else
        {
            // Substitute word1[index1] for word2[index2]
            numSubs++;
            index1++;
            index2++;
        }
    }

    return numDeletions + numInsertions + numSubs;
}
```

Comment: If the code is otherwise working as expected, consider posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like a question for code review

Comment: Seems to give the wrong result for `"avarice"` and `"vase"`... should be 4 (Delete A, Delete R, Delete I, Substitute S for C) but returns 5 instead.

Comment: Another test case: `"crevasse"` and `"vase"`.  Returns 8, should be 4

Comment: Or `"strange"` and `"rangers"`, returns 7 should be 4.

Comment: I also note an interesting related question in the sidebar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057513/levenshtein-distance-algorithm-better-than-onm?rq=1

Comment: The Levenshtein algorithm is provably correct. Your implementation of the algorithm, however, is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a comment, but I feel it is probably suitable as an answer:

Short answer is "no", if you want the true shortest distance for any given inputs.

The reason your code appears more efficient (and the reason that other implementations create a matrix instead of doing what you're doing) is that your stepwise implementation ignores a lot of potential solutions.

Examples @BenVoigt gave illustrate this, another perhaps clearer illustration is `("aaaardvark", "aardvark")` returns 8, should be 2: it's getting tripped up because it's matching the first `a` and thinking it can move on, when in fact a more optimal solution would be to consider the first two characters insertions.

Comment: Interesting side note that I haven't investigated: `("Aardvark", "aardvark")` returns 2 instead of 1 (or 0).  Perhaps one thing you might improve if you decide to go with this routine anyway is to standardise the case before processing (or provide a case sensitive switch as a parameter)