# string matching - best distance algorithm to use

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching, jaro-winkler

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, that have information about polling stations. The dataframes are of different lengths. Both dataframes have a column called `ps_name`, which is the name of the polling stations, and a column called `district` that indicates which district the polling stations are located.

I am trying to match strings on the `ps_name` column while blocking on the `district` column, so I can copy a `geolocations` (latitude and longitude) column on matches from `df1` to `df2`.

So far I've tried using *jaro-winkler* at threshold `0.88` to compare strings.

```
# Matched:
**df1:** AGRICULTURAL OFFICE ATTOCK (MALE) I (P)
**df2:** AGRICULTURAL OFFICE ATTOCK (MALE) (P)

# Did not match:
**df1:** govt girls high school peoples colony attock ii
**df2:** high school peoples colony attock ii
```

**What string distance algorithm should I be using**? I've tried *jaro-winkler* and was also considering *smith-waterman*.

Comment: I have another question: one of the pairs of polling stations that are getting matched while they shouldn't be matched have the following format: 'government high school X', 'government high school Y'. They are being matched because X and Y are short words. I was thinking of separating the string out into 'government high school' and 'X', 'Y' to match 'X' and 'Y' instead of the entire strings, but I wonder how this could work for the rest of the pairs that don't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is implemented in the package [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) (or [here](https://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/)), the algorithm runs in O(n + d^2), where n is the length of the longer string and d is the edit distance.

Example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
fuzz.ratio('govt girls high school peoples colony attock ii','high school peoples colony attock ii') 
#87
fuzz.ratio('AGRICULTURAL OFFICE ATTOCK (MALE) I (P)', 'AGRICULTURAL OFFICE ATTOCK (MALE) (P)')
#97
```

Comment: how do you come to the result, that the Levenshtein distance can be calculated in O(n + d^2)? Shouldn't it be O(N*M), since it has to iterate over both strings in a nested loop?

Comment: @maxbachmann see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057513/levenshtein-distance-algorithm-better-than-onm